Property of type String or Blank in record schema definition
In Copilot Studio, I'm receiving an object from an HTTP response where one of the properties can be either a string value or blank (null). However, I can't figure out how to define that type in the schema editor for the variable type. If I define it like this
kind: Record
properties:
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  middleName: String   <--- This should be String or Blank (null)

I get an error in Copilot Studio when the middleName property is null: Error Message: The provided value for path ‘Topic.Response.middleName’ cannot be parsed into ‘StringDataType’ type. Provided value: Error Code: ValueParsingError.
I can set the type to Any
middleName: Any

and get it working that way, but I prefer not to use that unless necessary. Is there a way to define the property type as String or Blank?
I've tried different variations based on TypeScript syntax or JSON definitions, such as:
middleName: String | Blank

middleName: String or Blank

middleName: [String, Blank]

middleName: ["String", "Blank"]

middleName: ["string", "null"]

but all of those definitions result in an error in the dialog window saying Unknown $kind: "undefined".
Is it possible to define the type as String or Blank or am I stuck using the Any type?
